# Youtube link gave me a virus?

Tags: virus, malware

I was watching a Youtube video, and I then clicked on a "View all replies" link under a comment. I tried this again 2 times, and none of the clicks had worked. Immediately afterwards, three console windows appeared and promptly disappeared (I had no time to see any text on them). I turned off my computer (I don't know why, just thought that maybe if it was a virus, it would stop it? Not logical, of course). I am now using my computer without any noticeable difference, but that doesn't mean it could not have been a virus. I do not have any anti-virus software installed (except for the built-in Windows Defender). If there is a good chance this could be a virus, what should I do?

Comment: The fact you're asking this question suggests you should have an AV installed

Answer (score 0):

## No, YouTube did not give you a virus

But that doesn't mean you don't already have one. YouTube can't launch console windows on your computer. Depending what you were doing at the time of clicking the link (like installing software, running updates, etc.) this may be normal but to be on the safe side, ditch Windows Defender and get (this is a personal recommendation)

- Super Anti Spyware & run a complete scan
- Comodo Internet Security & run a complete scan

Each are free and would pick up any common types of viruses that your computer may be infected with.

Answer (score -2):

This has, in fact, given me adware. I can no longer use Google Chrome (Microsoft Edge works fine, without ads). When ever I use Google Chrome, websites are loaded with ads, and I cannot use the websites. Google Chrome, at the bottom bar, said Waiting for castalemedia.com, so I am assuming that Is the virus I must remove.

EDIT:
It turns out it is not giving me ads any more, after running CCLeaner... let's hope it stays that way